# How to use setTimeout in order to achieve both typewriter effects sequently, printing a line character by delayed character and line by delayed line?

Tags: javascript, async-await, promise, generator, settimeout

I'm trying to build out a way to have multiple lines of strings "typed" out on a website. I've been writing a new function for every line, but now I'm trying to setup one function to loop through an array of strings, and type each string out on a new line. However, I can't get the timeouts right and only get the first string, and part of the 3rd string to actually type out. Is there a better way to calculate the timeouts, or a better way to get the functions to run consecutively rather than at the same time? I'm trying to stick with vanilla javascript, so no jquery please.

```js
var typeSpeed = 75;
var newSpan = '<span></span><br>';

function newTextSegment() {
  i = 0;
  j = 0;
  stringsArray = ['Type Line 1.', 'Type Line 2.', 'Type Line 3.'];
  arrayLength = stringsArray.length;
  typeLinesConsecutively();
}

function typeLinesConsecutively() {
  if (j < arrayLength) {
    segmentString = stringsArray[j];
    delay = segmentString.length * typeSpeed;

    document.querySelector('body').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', newSpan);

    typewriter();

    j++;

    setTimeout(typeLinesConsecutively, delay);
  }
}

//This is the function that will type out letter by letter
function typewriter() {
  var allSpan = document.querySelectorAll('span');
  if (i < segmentString.length) {
    allSpan[allSpan.length - 1].innerHTML += segmentString.charAt(i);
    i++;
    setTimeout(typewriter, typeSpeed);
  }
}

window.onload = (event) => {
  console.log('page loaded');
  newTextSegment();
};
```

Comment: Don't use two timing loops. Simply use a single timing loop and use regular if/else logic to decide what to do **now** inside that one timing loop

Comment: @StevenBowers ... From the so far provided sole answer / approach are there any questions left?

Answer (score 1):

The OP's approach of a recursively delayed function forces one to stick to exactly a single task which then needs to be implemented in a way that all logic (whether to render a new line and/or to type a new character) has to be carried by it.

In order to provide a solution with line and character specific tasks one has to choose an approach of higher abstraction.

The next provided one is based on two generically implemented functions ...

- the first one creating an [async function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) which returns any provided value with a value specific delay (deferred value) based on resolving a [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/Promise),
- and the second one being an **asynchronous** [generator function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*) which creates an **async** [generator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Generator) of deferred values from a list/array of async functions which each returns a deferred value.

Re-using this two functions twice enables a solution which iterates deferred `line` values (with a new line specific delay) and for each line iterates deferred `char` values (with a character specific (typing) delay) both times by [`for-await...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for-await...of#examples).

Both functions can be invoked with optional settings for e.g.

- a specific root node,
- a custom line-template (provided as markup string),
- custom delays (in msecs) for either new line- and/or character-insertion

```js
async function* createDeferredValuesPool(asyncFunctions) {
  let asyncFct;
  while (asyncFct = asyncFunctions.shift()) {

    yield (await asyncFct());
  }
}
function createDeferredValueAction(value, delay) {
  return async function () {
    return await (
      new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, delay, value))
    );
  }
}

async function typeLine(rootNode, line, lineTemplate, charDelay) {
  rootNode
    .insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', lineTemplate);

  const lineNode = [...rootNode
    .querySelectorAll('[data-line-content]')
  ]
  .slice(-1)[0]; // instead of the not entirely supported `.at(-1)`.

  const deferredCharacterActions = line
    .split('')
    .map(char =>
      createDeferredValueAction(char, charDelay)
    );
  const deferredCharactersPool =
    createDeferredValuesPool(deferredCharacterActions);

  for await (const char of deferredCharactersPool) {
    lineNode.textContent = lineNode.textContent + char;
  }
}
async function typeLines(
  rootNode = document.body,
  lines = [],
  lineTemplate = '<p data-line-content></p>',
  lineDelay = 200,
  charDelay = 10,
) {
  const deferredNewLineActions = lines
    .map(line =>
      createDeferredValueAction(line, lineDelay)
    );
  const deferredNewLinesPool =
    createDeferredValuesPool(deferredNewLineActions);

  for await (const line of deferredNewLinesPool) {

    await typeLine(rootNode, line, lineTemplate, charDelay);
  }
}

(async () => {
  await typeLines(
    document.body,
    ['Type Line 1.', 'Type Line 2.', 'Type Line 3.'],
    '<span data-line-content></span><br>',
    400,
    30,
  );
  await typeLines(
    document.body,
    ['And 2 lines, created by ...', '... default type-settings.'],
  );
})();
```