# Wait for recursive function to complete javascript

Tags: javascript, html, wait

I'm quite rusty on my javascript and I'm using the code from this answer in a text game to animate text.

[Show text letter by letter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7264974/show-text-letter-by-letter)

```
var showText = function (target, message, index, interval) {   
    if (index < message.length) {
      $(target).append(message[index++]);
      setTimeout(function () { showText(target, message, index, interval); }, interval);
    }
}
```

I'd like to wait until its finished to reveal a button but no matter how I edit it, nothing seems to wait, it just moves on right away. Is there any solution or better way to show the text?

Comment: so add an else and show the button

Comment: On a JS note, why are you using a `var showText = function...` instead of just declaring the function normally, i.e. `function showText(...) { ... }`?

Comment: @epascarello anything i put in the else doesnt get run

Comment: How about then [getting inspired by an approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72457726/how-to-use-settimeout-in-order-to-achieve-both-typewriter-effects-sequently-pri/72460600#72460600) which utilizes [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) and the [async await syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added an if statement inside of the setTimeout so that when the last letter shows, the button will show at the same time. If I added it as an else if of the existing if statement, it waited the interval time after the last letter was shown to show the button.

```js
var showText = function(target, message, index, interval) {

  if (index < message.length) {
    $(target).append(message[index++]);
    setTimeout(function() {
      showText(target, message, index, interval);
      if (index == message.length - 1) {
        $("#btn").show()
      }
    }, interval);


  }
}

showText($("#box"), "TEST", 0, 1000)
```

```css
#btn {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="box"></div>
<button id="btn">Show</button>
```