# simple type writer animation in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

I want to make an animation of type writer so when it reaches the last world it just delete everything and start over. so what can I do to make it simple ?

```
<body>
    <h1 id="main-text">
      <span id="sp1"></span>
    </h1>

    <script>
      let mainText = document.getElementById("main-text");
      let txt1 = "this is the main text!!!";
      let sp1 = document.getElementById("sp1");
      let cnt = 0;
      let txt1Handle = document.getElementById(txt1);

        let myInterval = setInterval(() => {
          let letter = document.createTextNode(txt1[cnt]);
          sp1.appendChild(letter);
          cnt++;
          console.log(cnt);
          if (cnt >= txt1.length) {
            cnt = 0;
            clearInterval(myInterval);
          }
        }, 200);

    </script>
  </body>
```

Comment: `document.getElementById(txt1)` what is this?

Comment: try to use async function and while loop

Comment: Deleting texts is not your only issue here. In your code there's not possibility to advance to the next texts and loop when necessary. An Array should be used instead.

Comment: So, can you comment please?! What about `txt2` and `txt3`? What's their purpose? To get into some other elements or to be the successive texts to be typewrited into the same element?

Comment: What's your specific question? What is your code doing that is different from your intended result? Do you get errors?  You should also use an array for your different texts.

Comment: What's the desired time to wait (for a better UX to allow the user to read the text in its entirety) before deleting and starting over?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use setTimeout in order to achieve both typewriter effects sequently, printing a line character by delayed character and line by delayed line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72457726/how-to-use-settimeout-in-order-to-achieve-both-typewriter-effects-sequently-pri)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you were looking for?  You could even add a small delay inbetween swapping the texts so users have more of a chance to read it.

```js
let txts = [];
txts.push("this is the main text!!!");
txts.push("this is the second text");
txts.push("this is the third text");

let sp1 = document.getElementById("sp1");
let cnt = 0;
let txtIndex = 0;



let myInterval = setInterval(() => {
   
  console.log(txts);

  sp1.textContent = txts[txtIndex].substring(0, cnt++);

  if (cnt > txts[txtIndex].length){
        cnt = 0;
    txtIndex++
        if (txtIndex >= txts.length) 
        txtIndex = 0;
  }

}, 100);
```

```html
<h1 id="main-text">
  <span id="sp1"></span>
</h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

- First of, create a reusable function that accepts two arguments, the element to target, and an Array of words to be typed in.
- Don't use `setInterval`, use `setTimeout` that recalls an inner `type` function. That way you can wait longer once a *text* is fully typed for a better UX
- use String.prototype.slice() to get the portion of text (from 0 to the incrementing `charIndex`) and use `Node.textContent` to print it as the element's text
- use the Modulo (Remainder) operator `%` to loop the text index back to `0`

```js
const typewriter = (el, texts) => {
  
  let textIndex = 0;
  let charIndex = 0;

  const type = () => {
    
    const text = texts[textIndex]; // Get the text by index
    const isEnded = charIndex >= text.length;
    const time = isEnded ? 1500 : 200; // Wait longer when text is fully typed
    el.textContent = text.slice(0, charIndex + 1);
    
    if (isEnded) {
      charIndex = 0; // Reset char index
      textIndex = ++textIndex % texts.length; // next text (and loop)
    } else {
      charIndex += 1; // increment character index
    }
    
    setTimeout(type, time); // Loop!
  };
  
  // Start!
  type();
};


typewriter(
  document.getElementById("sp1"),
  ["Main!!", "Second text", "Third text example"]
);

typewriter(
  document.getElementById("sp2"),
  ["code", "examples", "quality"]
);
```

```html
<div id="sp1"></div>
We provide <span id="sp2"></span>
```

For completeness, *"simple"* - but unsure if that's exactly the desired... here's the *simple*:

```js
const typewriter = (el) => {
  const text = el.dataset.typewriter;
  let i = 0;
  setInterval(() => {
    i = ++i % (text.length + 1);
    el.textContent = text.slice(0, i);
  }, 200);
};

document.querySelectorAll("[data-typewriter]").forEach(typewriter);
```

```html
<span data-typewriter="Main text!!!"></span>
```